Convert MATLAB .m Files to a .jar File for Use in a Java Project in MATLAB R2024a
I'm working with MATLAB R2024a and I have several .m files, each defining a different function. I need to convert all these .m files into a single .jar file so that I can use these functions in a Java project.
How can I achieve this?
Here's an example of what one of my .m files looks like:
function [output] = myFunction(input)
    ...
end


To do this, you need to use the Library Compiler (see doc: https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-java-application-with-matlab-code.html). You can specify multiple "exported functions" to be included in your .jar file.

Thank you for your answer. However, if I understand correctly, "Library Compiler" is part of "MATLAB Compiler SDK" which is a paid extension (or in any case not included in the Matlab trial period). Is there also a free alternative or is this the only way?

@El_Merendero the free alternative is that you re-implement all those functions in Java by hand.
